# How to stop loop execution in another file using telegram api?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

How to stop a function located in another file using a button in a telegram?

Main file:

```
import time
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'], content_types='text')
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='stop', callback_data='stopfunc'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Меню', reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    """Функция обработки кнопок"""
    if call.data == 'stopfunc':
        pass   # What to add here ??
```

Second file:

```
def test_func():
    while True:
        print("Hello")
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pid of the second process using

```py
from subprocess import check_output
def get_pid(name):
    return check_output(["pidof",name])
```

*replace **name** with the name of the second file*

After getting the PID, you can kill it using

```py
os.kill(pid, 9)
```